# Применение moxy + запуск новой активити

Tags: android, moxy

Помогите найти ответ на вопрос. Использую библиотеку MVP + moxy. При совершении некоторого события в Presenter запускается новая Activity. Всё работает, вопросов нету. 
Появился баг, что при повороте устройства, совершается переход в активити, если до этого переходили в неё. Никакие другие стратегии moxy не помогают решить проблему.

Comment: Попробуйте [стратегии](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy/wiki/View-commands-state-strategy) `OneExecutionStateStrategy` или `SkipStrategy`